# With Ruby on Rails, how to open a Rails Console and automatically run a command?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bash, rails-console

**Edit:** The console should remain open afterwards. I don't want to run a console command outside of the console.

I open a Rails Console like this from a Bash prompt: `bundle exec rails console`

Every time I open it, I need to run a command like this: `SomeModule::SomeClass.someMethod('myString')`

I'd like to combine these two commands into a single one that looks something like this: `bundle exec rails console -s myString` (or more likely a compact Bash function).

I tried `bundle exec rails console && SomeModule::SomeClass.someMethod('myString')` and `bundle exec rails console; SomeModule::SomeClass.someMethod('myString')` but those did not work.

Answer (score 1):

Why you want this in rails console? Rails have rake task to do so, which can be defined as below

```
namespace :pick do
  desc "Pick a random user as the winner"
  task :winner => :environment do
    puts "Winner: #{pick(User).name}"
  end

  desc "Pick a random product as the prize"
  task :prize => :environment do
    puts "Prize: #{pick(Product).name}"
  end

  desc "Pick a random prize and winner"
  task :all => [:prize, :winner]

  def pick(model_class)
    model_class.find(:first, :order => 'RAND()')
  end
end
```

and executed by rake pick:winner. You can write any ruby code inside `task :prize => :environment do` and `end`

Check out more at http://railscasts.com/episodes/66-custom-rake-tasks

Or

you can write initializer to do so inside `config/initializers/` and conditionally specify code to run like,

```
if defined?(Rails::Console)
 # in Rails Console
else
 # Not in Rails Console
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using [marco-polo](https://github.com/arches/marco-polo) gem for this purpose. Add the gem to the Gemfile, create `.irbrc.rb` and add `SomeModule::SomeClass.someMethod('myString')` to it.

UPD: Also, if you don't want to leave the console opened after you ran the command, just rails runner:

```
bundle exec rails runner "SomeModule::SomeClass.someMethod('myString')"
```